# Needing to get first of month in SQL Server, but from yesterday's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am working on a report that will send daily with the full months data minus the current day as it sends early and won't have relevant data from today.

Currently the parameter for the start as =dateadd(“m”,1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))

and the end as =DateAdd("d",-1,Today())

The problem is that this will skip the last day of each month. I want to change the start date to the first of the month from today - 1 day, but I am not sure how to do this?

I could change it to send with the current days data as well but with it sending at 8 AM the data would still be missing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably least amount of code is to (1) subtract a day from today, (2) take the eomonth of the *previous* month, and (3) add a day.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()),-1));
```

I'm not sure what language you're doing `dateserial` stuff in but I'd personally do this inside SQL Server.

Also the best way to drive a report for any period is to say:

```
col >= start of the period
AND
col <  start of *next* period
```

For example, for a report to cover all of last month (I realize that's not *quite* what you're doing, it's just a simpler example), I would say:

```
DECLARE @start date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2));

...
WHERE date_column >= @start
  AND date_column <  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @start);
```

This way you don't get bitten by all of the problems that can happen with various date/time types as you try to figure out what is the end of a day or month.

For month-to-date covering yesterday and not today, I would say:

```
DECLARE @today date = GETDATE();
DECLARE @start date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -1, @today),-1));

... WHERE date_column >= @start
      AND date_column <  @today;
```

Comment: I think you mixed up your conditions in example about taking last month. It should be `WHERE date_column > @start
  AND date_column <=  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @start);` Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @Aarlaneth I did miss adding a day, you're right about that, but I always assume the columns _might be_ date/time so I would never do `> AND <=`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is actually using Microsoft Visual Basic. It's the expression for my parameter on an SSRS report. Sorry for not clarifying that within the question.

Comment: @Triston77 I would still just have SQL Server calculate what today is, what last month is, etc. if this is the default behavior of this report. e.g. only pass dates if the user can override by picking their own dates from a calendar control etc.

Comment: @Rhythm Was a Lurker Got it working, thank you for the help!